# Sorting issue in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using client side angular js sorting .And it is working for first block which i pasted below .I have same kind of four block with different status.I am using filter concept for displaying List .
But when i am sorting with second or third block it is sorting the first block.

```
<ul class="unstyled listResultsAlignment itemdis{{(items|filter:{status:&quot;WCH&quot;}).length}}">
    <li><span class="span3">SORT BY : </span> 

    <select data-ng-model="sortorder" class="span6 itemselect">
    <option disabled value="">Choose one</option>
    <option value="createDateTime">Most Recent</option>                 
    <option value="title">Title</option>
    <option value="createdBy">Created By</option>                   
    </select>


    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="item-list: list" data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{status:&quot;WCH&quot;} | orderBy:sortorder" data-ng-click="displayDossierItem('WCH')">
    </div>
    </ul>
```

Please suggest ,i am new to angular concept

My second block

```
<ul class="unstyled listResultsAlignment itemdis{{(items|filter:{status:&quot;POI&quot;}).length}}">
    <li><span class="span3">SORT BY : </span> 

    <select data-ng-model="sortorder" class="span6 itemselect">
    <option disabled value="">Choose one</option>
    <option value="createDateTime">Most Recent</option>                 
    <option value="title">Title</option>
    <option value="createdBy">Created By</option>                   
    </select>


    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="item-list: list" data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{status:&quot;WCH&quot;} | orderBy:sortorder" data-ng-click="displayDossierItem('WCH')">
    </div>
    </ul>
```

Here i am changing status only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the same model for sorting all the blocks:

You can use different models to retain the order in your blocks:

```
<!-- 1st block -->
<select data-ng-model="sortorder1" class="span6 itemselect">
<!-- ... -->
<div class="item-list: list" data-ng-repeat="item in items | 
filter:{status'WCH'} | orderBy:sortorder1" 
data-ng-click="displayDossierItem('WCH')">
<!-- ... -->

<!-- 2nd block -->
<select data-ng-model="sortorder2" class="span6 itemselect">
<!-- ... -->
<div class="item-list: list" data-ng-repeat="item in items | 
filter:{status:'WCH'}   | orderBy:sortorder2" 
data-ng-click="displayDossierItem('WCH')">
<!-- ... -->
```

I would also suggest you to put those closing `</li>` tags that I found missing in your code.

Comment: I tried this solution , First block is working ,But second block is not sorting

Comment: @prash Did you exactly do as shown? `ng-model="sortorder2"` and `orderBy:sortorder2` ?